# Build task exits with code -2146233082

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, error-code

I have problem. When I build my C# .NET 4.5 project, I get this result from a custom build-task:

```
The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin\ccrefgen.exe" "@obj\Debug\DataStructuresccrefgen.rsp"" exited with code -2146233082.
```

But it isn't a problem of Microsoft Code Contracts, since it has worked before for weeks without any strange errors. Additionally, "PowerShellTools Host Service" crashes at start of Visual Studio. Also, "vshost32.exe" crashes sometimes.

I already repaired Visual Studio and rebooted my PC, but that doesn't solve the issue.

I did some research on the issue and from Google I got only some comparable results who point to a Microsoft Hotfix that applies to .NET 3.5, but nothing that applies to .NET 4.5.

Does someone has a suggestion?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: I could, but the code compiles fine. Until the build task comes into the picture.

Comment: Have you tryd to cut the bin and place it somewhere else, then rebuild it?

Comment: The project compiles and runs just fine on other computers. It is just my PC.

Comment: Try to copy the whole solution to an external disk (USB) and run it from there.

Comment: That's the dreaded ExecutionEngineException, instant failure.  Usually caused by GC heap corruption.  Maybe best thing to do is drag the machine to a forth story floor and let it slip out of a window.  Opening the window first is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed it. As it turned out, I should not have installed .NET 4.6 preview on my Windows 7 workstation (https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/download/details.aspx?id=44928).

Then, I tried to enable "RyuJIT" with the register key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AltJit`

The only effect of enabling RyuJIT on Widnows 7 was that it started to destroy many (but not all) .NET assemblies at runtime

Removing .NET 4.6 Preview **and** the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AltJit` key from the Windows Register solved the issue.